# Isolation levels in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I would like to know different isolation levels with respect to commit, and would also like to know about row-level and table-level lock.

Comment: Google on isolation level oracle
The is a lot of Fine Material available, i.e.: * http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html * http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10743/consist.htm Topic is too big to answer in SO.

Answer (score 11):

ANSI/ISO SQL defines four isolation levels:

- serializable
- repeatable read
- read committed
- read uncommitted

According to Oracle's Database Development Guide, [chapter 6.6.1: Transaction Interaction and Isolation Level](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_sqlproc.htm#BEJDDAGA), you can request either isolation level `READ COMMITTED` (the default) or `SERIALIZABLE`.

Please note, however, that what Oracle call `SERIALIZABLE` is actually [snapshot isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation).

For more information about row-level and table-level locks, see [Overview of the Oracle Database Locking Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1331) and [Locking tables explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_sqlproc.htm#ADFNS00203).

Answer (score -4):

There are four isolation levels

1. Read uncommitted or Read Dirty Buffers
2. Read Committed or repeated reads
3. Phantom reads
4. Serializable